# Textbox autocomplete by json

Tags: c#, jquery, json, autocomplete

I am having problem while passing json data to the  source of autocomplete multiselect jquery 
this is the jason data which i am sending

```
[  "abhinav@sdv.com","nishimura@dscs.com","alex@sds.com","alice@sdvs.com","amit@sds.com"]



autocomplete: {
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                url: "/CommanService.asmx/ExtractEmail",
                                data: {},
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (data) {

                                    var vServiceData = eval(data);
                                    // alert(data.d[0].data123);
                                    //return eval('[' + data.d + ']');
                                    //response(vServiceData);
                                    // alert(data);
                                    response(data);

                                },
                                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                    alert(xhr.status);
                                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                                    alert(thrownError);
                                }

                            })
                        }
```

in this source of ajax but the problem here is that istead of getting these record in 
diffrent string the output is in the form of single string but when i pass static data like

source=["Red","blue","green"]

MY webservice code is

```
#region(EXTRACT EMAIL)
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public string ExtractEmail()
    {
        //Webservice is used to extract the employee data 
        VisualLibrarySoapClient oVisualLibrary = new VisualLibrarySoapClient();
        string data = oVisualLibrary.EmployeeSelectData();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = GetDataSet(data);

        //Used data columns to extract email from data set
        DataColumn ColEmail = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Email"];

        //all emails are stored in a linst Mail
        List<string> Mail = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            String MailData = row[ColEmail].ToString();
            Mail.Add(MailData);
        }

        //Json serializer is used to convert the list data into jason format 
        //System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        // string a = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Mail);
        string ss = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Mail, Formatting.Indented);

        string d = ss.Substring(1, ss.Length - 1).ToString();
        return ss;
        //System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        //return serializer.Serialize(Mail);

    }
    #endregion
```

directly in the source then the output is right i am getting this three words diffrently in autocomplete textbox suggestions plzz help thanx in advance

Comment: your data: attribute is empty

Comment: there is no parameter to be passed in the calling method

Comment: please tell what error message you are getting

Comment: there is no error the  thing i want is that autocompete suggesstions should come diffrently but this code is taking all of the data as a single string suggestion, plz if you have a working code of multiselect textbox from database give it to me sir..